# Setup TURN server in AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, nat, turn

I have setup TURN server on EC2 instance using below link:
https://medium.com/@omidborjian/setup-your-own-turn-stun-signal-relay-server-on-aws-ec2-78a8bfcb71c3

But when I test in https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/trickle-ice/
I get following error:

> Note: errors from onicecandidateerror above are not neccessarily fatal. For example an IPv6 DNS lookup may fail but relay candidates can still be gathered via IPv4.
>
> The server stun:xx.xx.xx.xx:3478 returned an error with code=701:
>
> STUN server address is incompatible.

Can anyone help? I have configured turnserver and created credentials using turnadmin command and added those credentials in turnserver.conf.

Comment: Also, iceconnectionstatechange is never going in connected state